# Let $A(x) = \sum_{n\leq x} a(n)$, is it possible that $A(x) = π(x) + O(\sqrt x)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $A(x) = \sum_{n\leq x} 
a(n)$,

where $a(n) = \frac{1}{k}$ if $n=p^k,$ p prime and is $0$ otherwise.

i believe that its possible to show that $A(x) = π(x) + O(\sqrt x \log(\log(x))$
is it possible to show that the better bound $A(x) = π(x) + O(\sqrt x)$ also holds?

(the answer may well be no)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $A(x)$ is often denoted by $\Pi(x)$, and called the Riemann Pi function. In particular,
$$A(x)=\Pi(x)=\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n}$$ where $\Lambda(n)$ is the Von Mangoldt Lambda function. By splitting up the sum based on the value of the exponent, we have that $$\Pi(x)=\pi(x)+\frac{\pi(\sqrt{x})}{2}+\frac{\pi(\sqrt[3]{x})}{3}+\cdots=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{\pi(\sqrt[j]{x})}{j}.$$
Using this identity, you can prove your desired result. (Or even something slightly stronger, with an additional $\log x$ in the denominator).

Comment: How much stronger can one get? (also  i dont see the result is immediately obvious from your identity but will spend some time with and accept when i feel i understand.)

Comment: The error $\Pi(x)-\pi(x)$ is exactly equal to $\sum_{j=2}^{\infty} \pi(\sqrt[j]{x})/j$. The terms in this sum are very small when $j$ grows, and vanish for $j>\log_2(x)$. In particular, the first term is dominant, and so $$\Pi(x)-\pi(x)\sim \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log x}.$$